# Matlab Legend after FOR loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, fft, legend, figure

I am creating a file to read in a certain number of .wav files, each of these corresponding to a musical note. I am performing an FFT on each of them and plotting them all on the same figure. However I am having a problem with getting the legend to print correctly, it is separating the names I want to use into individual letters instead of using them as a string. My code is as follows:

```
clear all
mydir = 'Note Values/';
wavFiles = dir([mydir '*.wav']);
length(wavFiles)

legendText = [];
figure(1);
hold on;
for i = 1:length(wavFiles)

    wavFiles(i).name
    [y, fs] = wavread([mydir wavFiles(i).name]);
    sound(y, fs)

    currentSample = y(round(length(y)/2)-2048:round(length(y)/2)+2047);

    FFT = abs(fft(currentSample));
    Power = FFT.*conj(FFT)/length(FFT);

    if (mod(i, 2) == 1)
        h = plot(Power, 'Color', 'red');

    else
        h = plot(Power, 'Color', 'blue');
    end

    sri = wavFiles(i).name;
    sri
    legendText = [legendText, sri];

end
length(legendText)
legendText(1)
legend(legendText(:));
hold off;
```

The sri variable is always a full string, but legendText(1) only prints out A instead of A3.wav. I know it's probably something really obvious but I just can't find it. Thanks

The output on my graph appears as this:
[image]

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you should plot the y-axis on a log-scale instead of linear. Use the `semilogy` function or simply: `set(gca, 'YScale','log')`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
legendText{i} = sri
```

to fill the cell with strings and

```
legend(legendText{:});
```

at end.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it was just going to be something small.

Comment: Regarding strings : array can only contain characters (that make one string). To get multiple strings, cell are the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MATLAB by me, so I'm not able to test it, but as I recall, you should use { instead of [ :

```
legendText = {legendText, sri};
```

Comment: I have tried using the {} brackets already and it results in legendText(1) containing {1x2 cell} which results in the following error. 

Error using ==> legend>process_inputs at 560
Cell array argument must be a cell array of strings.

And the second element in the cell array is the name of the last file processed.

Comment: By doing that, you create a cell containing a cell and a string.